# CAML query cant read serverrelatedURL with special character

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml

My scenario :

I am using a caml query to read all folder and files in a list but i noticed that if i get a folder by serverrelativeURl and the list name is(eg késhév,ie has special character or a space),the caml query return null.

For other list with standard name the codes work.

I am trying to use CDATA,but its not working.i think its a syntax error.

```
 var query = new CamlQuery();

            query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folderServerRelativeUrl;

            query.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> " +
                "<Query>" +
                "<Where>" +
                            "<Eq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" />" +
                                "<Value Type=\"Text\">" + "<![CDATA["+folderServerRelativeUrl+"]]>" + "</Value>" +
                             "</Eq>" +
                "</Where>" +
                "</Query>" +
                "</View>";

            ListItemCollection folderItems = list.GetItems(query);
            clientContext.Load(folderItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Try with the encoded value (k%C3%A9sh%C3%A9v).

Answer (score 3):

Encode the values:

```
encodeURIComponent('listname') in javascript
Uri.EscapeUriString("listname") in C#
```

Comment: I am using c# and not javascript. Is there an equivalent

Comment: Use Uri.EscapeUriString("listname") in C#

Answer (score 1):

Include the text containing special characters in `CDATA`. See this for reference: http://code2care.org/2015/error-caml-query-containing-special-characters/

Comment: Can you verify the code above please,i can't seem to be able to use a variable in CDATA